# Retrieving user data from Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. The user name in Firebase is not being retrieved and updated.

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="header">
<div class="userPanel">
  <div class="pic"></div>
  <div class="welcome"><span>Welcome</span><h1 class="name" id="firstname">John</h1></div>
</div>
<div class="title"></div>
```

JS code:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
 if (user) {
console.log(user.uid);

var userRef = firebase.database().ref().child('Users')
var uid = user.uid;
var firstname = document.getElementById('firstname');

firebase.database().ref('Users/' + uid).on('value', function(snapshot){

  var firstname.innerHTML = snapshot.val().Firstname;

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the uid is `undefined` in the screenshot of your Firebase database. I'm guessing the `user.uid` you `console.log` is not `undefined`. What is output in your console?

Also, take out `var` in `var firstname.innerHTML`. You're not declaring a new variable called `firstname.innerHTML`.

Comment: i was able to fix that, the uid is defined now

Comment: You take out `var`?

Comment: sorry i meant i figured out why the kid was undefined, the problem i really had was retrieving the user data from firebase so that it will say "Welcome (user first name)" per the html code above

Comment: If removing the `var` from `var firstname.innerHTML` doesn't solve the issue, do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: Thank you, it worked! I can't its something that simple